# Penalty of AtomicVariables over locks in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, atomic

For my current project, i try to use Atomic Integers and Atomic Booleans where ever possible when we have more than 1 thread accessing it. This helps in keeping the logic lock free(Internally i know it may still use locks) and the code much cleaner. The use case is mostly for configuration tags which may change abruptly.

I want to know what is the penalty performance wise of using Atomic Variables, will this invalidate the cache far too often and actually make my solution inferior than just using locks?

Answer (score 0):

atomic* classes does not use locks, it uses CAS (compare-and-set) to achieve thread-safety. in general they are faster then locking variant, however under very high contention they tends to be actually slower. 
if you want some analogy, it is something like optimistic and pessimistic locking in DB.

if you are interested in more details, you might want to check [Java Performance: The Definitive Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449358454) book.

**ADD**: With cache I assume you are referring to *happens-before relationship*. Here is quote from [oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomicvars.html):

> The java.util.concurrent.atomic package defines classes that support
>   atomic operations on single variables. All classes have get and set
>   methods that work like reads and writes on volatile variables. That
>   is, a set has a happens-before relationship with any subsequent get on
>   the same variable.

Comment: Do you know if it invalidates the thread cache as volatile variables access do?

Comment: @sodik It is not true that atomic classes will never use locks. In case there is no support for Atomic in the machine, internally JVM will replace the logic with locks. That is my understanding.

Comment: hm. I thought you are referring to `java.util.concurrent.locks` (and/or `synchronized` equivalent). of course I don't know what happens in internal JVM code. if we talk about various/all possible architectures where Java can run, then it is very hard to give general statement about penalties/performance. in such case I can only suggest you golden rule of performance tuning : "always measure your case".

Comment: Atomic* classes _may_ use locks, but probably don't in most practical JVMs running on typical, modern, server or workstation hardware.  CAS is only available on some architectures;  Other architectures use different instructions (e.g., load-linked and store-conditional) to achieve the same end.